# How can I increase the performance of OpenVPN over a high packet loss network environment

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, packet-loss

I am trying to connect my laptop to a server in another continent, and it seems that the link is very unreliable (with about 58% packet loss when pinging).

When using the VPN through a default OpenVPN's secret key setting (which uses UDP), pinging in the VPN reports about 57% packet loss (it bothers me in ways like a slow SSH establishment).

Is there an efficient way to decrease the packet loss rate in this situation? I have administrative control on both my laptop and the server.

---

Here is part of the traceroute result from my laptop to the server:

```
 8  221.176.27.254 (221.176.27.254)  16.870 ms
 9  * * *
10  221.183.30.246 (221.183.30.246)  197.288 ms
11  223.118.10.30 (223.118.10.30)  201.422 ms
```

Comment: Determine the cause of the packet loss.  Change your DNS route if you have to.

Comment: Those two points are in china.... if your traffic is trans-versing into/out of china, you're going to hit the great firewall. Have fun convincing the chinese to fix that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [UDPspeeder](https://github.com/wangyu-/UDPspeeder). It trades bandwidth overhead for packet loss resistance.

On server side, start

```
speederv2_amd64 -s -l 0.0.0.0:1193 -r 127.0.0.1:1194
```

On client side, start

```
speederv2_amd64 -c -l 127.0.0.1:1194 -r your_server_ip:1993
```

Then point OpenVPN UDP client to 127.0.0.1:1194.

Use `--fec` parameter to tune amount of redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle OpenVPN to TCP in the configs (Do both client and server, and maybe ensure your TCP OpenVPN is secure before or if you disable the UDP service).  This will have the effect of ensuring all packets get through eventually.  This will still be slow, but it's at least worth the experiment.  From openvpn.net:

> If you want your OpenVPN server to listen on a TCP port instead of a UDP port, use `proto tcp` instead of `proto udp` (If you want OpenVPN to listen on both a UDP and TCP port, you must run two separate OpenVPN instances).

---

As for packet loss, you can only fix the path the packets take.  Use traceroute from both ends to find the offending portion of the link and see about bypassing it or making it more robust.

Instead of TCP the whole way, try seeing if you can rent infrastructure time very near the suffering link to tunnel TCP through the weak link to the destination.  This would let UDP packets fly as far as possible without having to TCP ack or retransmit for the entire length of your tunnel, only the bad part of it.

If the weak link is mid-way through, you may benefit from renting infrastructure on both ends of the weak link instead of just on one side, but if we're talking Antarctica, maybe that would be difficult.

If you chose to test this route, I recommend udptunnel as one possible solution.  (`udptunnel` is its own package on Ubuntu, but other options like socat or creative netcat piping will work.)

Comment: Changing to TCP decreases the packet loss rate (to 23%), but the average ping delay becomes over 60 seconds. It is difficult for me to add any infrastructures in the link.

Comment: Can you at least see where the bad link is with traceroute?  Pinpointing that will at least clarify what options you might have.  To clarify, by "rent infrastructure", my thinking was along the lines of this example:  Connect from Honolulu to middle-of-nowhere-eastern California.  It turns out the bad link is between SanFran and Middle-of-nowhere.  Rent an AWS instance in California.  Go UDP VPN all-the-way-through, but tunnel the vpn packets through one TCP connection between SanFran and Middle-of-nowhere.  Is this solution (potentially) applicable to your specific scenario?

Comment: It seems that the link with the longest delay occurs at this hop, but what can I do with it (renting a server is kind of difficult for me)? 
I have attached the traceroute result at my question.